# I got a glibc detected error

Tags: c++

I am trying to create an array that, when filled, will cause a new bigger array to be created, will copy the values of the old array into the previous array, and will continue adding values to the new array from where the old one left off. My code works fine while I'm adding to the first array, but once I try to call append after I've filled up the original array, I end up getting a weird error:

```
*** glibc detected *** demo: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000602010 ***
```

No clue what's going on! I'm not really sure why.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ArrayList {
public: 
    int* array;
public:
    int capacity = 0;
    int size = 16;

    ArrayList() {
        array = new int(size);
    }

    void append(int data) {
        if (size == capacity) {
            int* tmp = new int(size+16);
            for (int i = 0; i != size; i++) {
                tmp[i] = array[i];
                delete [] array;
            }
            array = tmp; 
        } else {
            array[capacity] = data;
            capacity++;
            // std::cout << *(array+15) << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: delete[] array is at the wrong place. It should be executed after the loop operation is finished.

Comment: I'm blinded by the whitespace.

Comment: @user2784234 hmm, I did that. I no longer get the error, but when I try to test what's in array[16] or beyond, it just gives me 0

Comment: Your array size is 16, and indices go from 0 to 15 - what do you expect for array[16] and beyond?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt but I created a new array size+16, then made array to point to it.

Comment: @FrostyStraw No you didn't, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for allocating an array is wrong - instead of

```
int* tmp = new int(size+16);
```

(which creates a new int and initializes it with the *value* size+16), you need

```
int* tmp = new int[size+16];
```

which creates a new int array with size+16 elements.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. However, I fixed that, and I'm still only getting a 0 when I try to see what's at array[16], even though when I'm calling append, I'm putting 4 as an argument